# Segmentation Fault when printing Struct Objects

Tags: c, struct

I've been reading around and I assume that I get this error due to not allocating a pointer before using it within my program. Is this the case? How would I go about doing so if it is? (HOMEWORK)

The Struct is in a file data.h

```
 typedef struct student
 {
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int GPA;
    float tuitionFees;
    int numClass;
}Student;
```

This is within a file called student.c

```
Student Student_create()
    {

        Student *myStudent = malloc(sizeof(Student));
        assert(myStudent != NULL);

        printf("Please enter a name: ");
        scanf("%20s",myStudent->firstName);
        printf("\nPlease enter a family name: ");
        scanf("%20s",myStudent->lastName);
        printf("\nEnter number of enrolled classes: ");
        scanf("%d",&myStudent->numClass);
        printf("\nEnter students GPA: ");
        scanf("%d",&myStudent->GPA);
        printf("\nEnter tuition Fee: ");
        scanf("%f",&myStudent->tuitionFees);

       return myStudent;
    }

    void Student_print(Student *who)
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("First Name: %s\n, ",who->firstName);
        printf("Last Name: %s\n", who->lastName);
        printf("\tTuition Fees: %f\n, ",who->tuitionFees);
        printf("Number of Courses: %d\n , ",who->numClass);
        printf("GPA : %d\n, ",who->GPA);
    }
```

And the main file I'm trying to access it through is labelled col_personal.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        //This is for the input
        int choice;
        mainMenu();


        return 0;
    }




void mainMenu()
{
    int choice = 0;
    Student class[10];
    int ssize = 0;
    while(choice != 10){
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t====School Database====\n");
        printf(" 1. Add a new record\n");
        printf(" 2. Print Students.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        //CHOICE ADD NEW RECORD.
        if(choice == 1)
        {

        printf("1.Student\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice == 1){
            printf("How many students would you like to input? ");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            //Creates Students
                for(int i=0; i<choice;i++){
                    class[i] = Student_create();
                    ssize = ssize + 1;
                }

            }


        //PRINTING STUDENTS CHOICE 2
        } else if (choice == 2){
            for(int i=0; i < ssize;i++){
                Student_print(class[i]);
            }
```

Comment: 'char *firstName;' and   'char *lastName;' don't seem to have any allocation before you try to scanf into them:(

Comment: Off-topic, since it is a "fix my buggy code" question without any explicit understanding from your part.... You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), use the debugger (`gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) & [ASAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and read the documentation of the standard functions you are using (`printf`: the `\n` should be at end of control string; `scanf`: you should check the count of scanned items)

Comment: Can I pass class[i] = Student_create(); like so?

Answer (score 1):

1. segmentation falut is due to no memory allocation for the pointers

`char *firstName;`
`char *lastName;`

these are just pointers not pointing to any valid memory location.
use 
`pointer = malloc(<number of character to store> * sizeof(char));`

Also free the allocated memory towards the end to avoid memory leak.

Comment: I was currently working with the students so it's all just placeholder information sorry. How can I make them point to valid memory location? Malloc them?

Comment: Should I malloc these within my Student_create function?

Comment: yeah you can allocate there.

Comment: so firstName = malloc(20*sizeof(char)); should allocate 20 chars to firstName? Do I have to give it a type declaration?

Comment: @Genesis `firstName` already has a type , `char *`, you don't need to add any warts if that's what you're asking. Also, `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` so you could omit that too.

Comment: I have now allocated both pointers
firstName = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
lastName = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

within the Student_create function. When calling the Student_print() function it hangs on segmentation fault still. Should it not be initialized or do I have to change how Student_print() finds the pointer?

Comment: @Genesis your code should not even compile, you pass a `Student` to the `Student_print` function but that function expects `Student *`.  Please check to see if there are any compiler messages you overlooked. Also, debug your code. You should be able to see for yourself which line is causing a segmentation fault. And if you are mallocing `20` then change scanf to have `19` where you currently have `255`.